# boost optional recognizes inheritance?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

void func(boost::optional<Base>&) {}

int main () {
  boost::optional<Derived> x;
  func(x);
}
```

will func accept both optionals: base and derived?

Comment: Accidentally while looking for other things I just stumbled upon "Coercion by Member Template" idiom (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Coercion_by_Member_Template) which fits nicely in this particular case. However `optional` (unlike `shared_ptr` for example) doesn't support it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it won't work. `func` takes an lvalue reference to `boost::optional<Base>`. That means it can accept an lvalue of type `boost::optional<Base>`, an lvalue of a type that derives publicly and unambiguously from `boost::optional<Base>`, or some other type that has an `operator boost::optional<Base>&()`. None of those is true of `boost::optional<Derived>`. Class templates are not coviarant in the C++ type system - `boost::optional<Derived>` does not inherit from `boost::optional<Base>`.

---

It would be a different story if `func` took its argument by value. If it looked like:

```
void func(boost::optional<Base> ) { }
```

In that case, you *could* call `func` with a `boost::optional<Derived>`. But that converting constructor is marked `explicit`, so you would have to write:

```
func(boost::optional<Base>{x});
```

It's good that this is explicit - you are marking clear that you are (potentially) slicing `x`.

Answer (score -1):

Even if it would work (which is likely buy I haven't checked) it would cause slicing. Only `Base` part would be stored in optional.

optional keeps internally a buffer of the size needed to store `Base`. And even if `Base` would be of the same size as `Derived` (as in your case) still it would store only `Base`.

---

**EDIT:**

Above answer was given for the original question which contained following code:

```
int main () {
  boost::optional x(Derived());
  func(x);
}
```

Such code is not correct because of two reasons:

1. `boost::optional` requires template argument
2. Even with the template argument it would still be function declaration.

I have ignored those issues and assumed that something like this was meant:

```
int main () {
  boost::optional<Base> x = Derived();
  func(x);
}
```

While that code does compile (at least Visual Studio 2013 and Boost 1.60) and causes slicing. As can be seen by running following program:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "~Base" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Derived() { std::cout << "~Derived" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    boost::optional<Base> x = Derived();
}
```

which produces output

```
~Derived
~Base
~Base
```

The second `~Base` shows that `optional` destroyes `Base` object rather than `Derived` object. (The `~Derived` is from the temporary object `Derived()` as is the first `~Base`.)

Comment: I thought the same about slicing but I thought that it might be storing references to the optional values not copies?

Comment: @mkmostafa I have edited my answer to provide more details. And also to explain original answer after you changed code in your question. Changed in a way making my original answer totally incorrect... If you would like to store the original object you might use mechanizm simialr to Boost.Any (Boost.Any itself will not be useful as well). Possibly Boost.TypeErasure has already something like this.